# Using apache.commons.lang in more eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am facing to the following problem:

I would like to use SerializationUtils from apache.commons.lang. Since it is part of the eclipse platform, it seems easy. However, when deserializing, it does not find the classes in my plugin.

And I don't want to hack the manifest.mf of apache.commons.lang (adding `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: dependent`), because I have to create a jar for a third-party component, which runs under tomcat6, and tomcat6 complains about wrong manifest.mf, if I hack the manifest.mf.

So basically I would like to use apache's SerializationUtils in 2-3 independent plugins without hacking apache's jar. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely you need to supply an appropriate ClassLoader to find the class for a given app. A class can be loaded many times in different applications and the ClassLoader determines which is the right copy to use.

I don't see how changing the manifest would help.

Comment: Adding Eclipse-BuddyPolicy would allow that plugin to access other plugins class.